# How can I get a list of column definitions of the return type of a table returning function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I am working on postgres 12. I have some functions defined that have TABLE(...) as return values. I know how to query the information_schema and/or pg_proc to get the list of arguments of the function given its name and schema. I would like to do something similar for the return type when it is a TABLE, that is, to find a query, that when the function returns a set of records, will return a list of the ordinal position and oid (or name) for the columns of the return table.

Is that possible?

EDIT: I know of pg_get_function_result() which returns the text of the return definition as it is written in the function definition but I would have to parse that and i wonder if there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_proc.prorettype` will contain the OID of the table's type, so you can use:

```
select prorettype::regtype::text
from pg_proc
where proname = 'your_function';
```

to get the name of the type - which is also the name of the table.

To get all the columns, you can join pg_proc with pg_class to get the table's oid and then use that to find the columns.

```
select col.attname, col.attnum, format_type(col.atttypid, col.atttypmod) as data_type
from pg_attribute col
where not attisdropped
  and attnum > 0
  and attrelid in (select tbl.oid
                   from pg_class tbl
                      join pg_proc p on p.prorettype = tbl.reltype
                   where p.proname = 'your_function_name_here')
order by col.attnum
```

---

If you need to get the column names returned by a function defined as `returns table()`, they are available in the array `pg_proc.proargnames` for those that are defined as "out" parameters through `proargmodes`

```
select t.column_name, t.arg_type::regtype::text, t.col_num
from pg_proc p
  cross join unnest(proargnames, proargmodes, proallargtypes) with ordinality as t(column_name, arg_mode, arg_type, col_num)
where p.proname = 'your_function_name_here'
  and t.arg_mode = 't'
order by t.col_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Run function **pg_get_function_result** with oid (object identifier)

```
SELECT * FROM pg_get_function_result(25709);

/*where 25709 - is oid*/
```

In order to find **oid** of your function/pocedure, run this query:

```
select n.nspname as schema_name,
       p.proname as specific_name,
       p.oid,
       case p.prokind
            when 'f' then 'FUNCTION'
            when 'p' then 'PROCEDURE'
            when 'a' then 'AGGREGATE'
            when 'w' then 'WINDOW'
            end as kind,
       l.lanname as language,
       case when l.lanname = 'internal' then p.prosrc
            else pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
            end as definition,
       pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as arguments,
       t.typname as return_type
from pg_proc p
left join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
left join pg_language l on p.prolang = l.oid
left join pg_type t on t.oid = p.prorettype
where n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')

order by schema_name,
         specific_name;
```