# How to get the full source code of a postgresql function

Tags: postgresql

I am using the following sql to get the definition of a function:

```
SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'my_func'
```

It works good but it doesn't include the `create or replace function my_func(args)` part, when I want to know the input arguments and output arguments, I have to read the code in the function body, which is not convenient.

So, I would ask how to get the full source code of the function body definition.

Comment: [Show the code of a function, procedure and trigger in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6898453/5298879)
[How do I find the implementation of an aggregate PostgreSQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77906742/5298879) 
[How can I get a list of column definitions of the return type of a table returning function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66100740/5298879) 
[How to read the function body of a Postgres standard-SQL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77006456/5298879) [Show full stored function or procedure code in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3524859/5298879)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the function definition you can use the following query.

```
select pg_get_functiondef(oid)
from pg_proc
where proname = 'functionname';
```